# Error "[: too many arguments" from bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
pathToTestCasesFile=$1

while IFS=';' read -r col1 col2
do

    if [[ $col1 == V[0-9]:* ]]; then
      echo "decrypt"
      if [[ "$(decrypt "$col1")" == "$col2" ]] ; then  
        echo "$col1 is equal to $col2"
      else
        echo "$col1 is not equal to $col2"
      fi
    else
       echo "encrypt"
       if [[ "$(encrypt $col1)" == "$col2" ]] ; then  
        echo "$col1 is equal to $col2"
      else
        echo "$col1 is not equal to $col2"
      fi
    fi

done < $pathToTestCasesFile

exit 0
```

Here is the test file:

```
alex;V1:IVjd9qcAbUrR954gyPDbKw==
V1:IVjd9qcAbUrR954gyPDbKw==;alex
```

The output looks like this:

```
encrypt
alex is not equal to V1:IVjd9qcAbUrR954gyPDbKw==
decrypt
V1:IVjd9qcAbUrR954gyPDbKw== is not equal to alex
decrypt
```

But the output should say that everything is equal.

I am sure that after the commands de -encrypt the value is equal to the other one. I tested it separately.

Maybe there is an issue with the comparisons..

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: The command says to me line 23: $pathToTestCasesFile: ambiguous redirect. Maybe the $?

Comment: Ok bro, you have to add double quotes in pathToTestCasesFile variable
"$pathToTestCasesFile:"

Comment: post a sample from the `./automatedRegressionTest` file contents

Comment: `if [ encrypt "$col1" == "$col2" ]` doesn't make sense. Are you trying to run the `encrypt`  (and decrypt) cmds inside of `if [ ...]` ? Won't work. Good luck.

Comment: Don't use `==` with `[`. Either use `=`, or switch to `[[`.

Comment: Thats a sample record of the .csv file: V1:sdfsfsfsff;Alex

Comment: What's the new error message? It's certainly not `[: too many arguments` since there is no `[` after the edit.

Comment: now there is no error message. but it seems like the string from the $col will be splittet... because the echo says that: 
| got:alex;V1:IVjd9qcAbUrR954gyPDbKw==                 

encrypt                 

 is not equal to UrR954gyPDbKw==

Comment: Sounds, then, like you've solved this issue and have a new and different problem -- which should be isolated as per the help center and then asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
    echo "I got|$col1|$col2|"

    if [[ "$col1" =~ V.:.* ]]; then
        echo "decrypt"
        if [[ "$(decrypt "$col1")" == "$col2" ]] ; then
            echo "[$col1] is equal to [$col2]"
        else
            echo "[$col1] is not equal to [$col2]"
        fi
    else
        echo "encrypt"
        if [[ "$(encrypt "$col1")" == "$col2" ]] ; then
            echo "[$col1] is equal to [$col2]"
        else
            echo "[$col1] is not equal to [$col2]"
        fi
    fi
done < "$pathToTestCasesFile"
```

for the field separator is used the `,` comma - as in your code. In the example data you have `;`. If you need `;` change the `IFS=,` to `IFS=';'`.

Comment: "Didn't work for me" is not helpful. What are you expecting, and what happened instead?

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the test data now. And when I applied your solution, the output was:

| got:Input;Erwarteter Output
 is not equal to Output
| got:Alex;V1:sdfsfsfsff
 is not equal to f
| got:V1:sdfsfsfsff;Alex
 is not equal to x
| got:Moage;V1:sdfgjhhkdf
 is not equal to df


So it seems like the script is splitting a String into many Strings.. But it shouldn't.

Comment: If using `[ ]` rather than `[[ ]]`, then `==` is wrong and the correct operator should be `=`; there is no `==` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah yes, i just copied the OP's line and doesn't pays attention to the `==` only to the argument count. Thanx. Correcting.

Comment: yea the program itself runs now. but the output is wrong. it always say that it's not equal. But it should be equal. I will update my question to show you what i mean.

Comment: Man, can't help more. The code is formally (+-) correct. (here is still a plenty of room for improvments), but I havent installed your `encrypt` and `decrypt` so i'm unable to verify the encryption and the decryption. The question was about the "too many agruments" **and this question is got answered.** If you have another problem - please, create a new specific question together with `verifiable` input/outputs. (encryption isn't the best one).